# summing op-amp: 2 voltages in parallel

Tags: operational-amplifier, parallel

I didn't quite get how this circuit from falstad works:
http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-amp-sum.html

[image]

Specifically, how can 2 voltages in parallel add up when negative input (ideally) has infinite resistance?

Answer (score 4):

There is no current flowing *into* the inverting (negative) input, because the input impedance of an ideal op-amp is infinite, therefore the current flowing through the feedback 1k\$\Omega\$ resistor (let's call it \$i_3\$) is the sum of the two currents flowing through the two other resistors (\$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$). The inverting input is a virtual ground, as the op-amp with negative feedback always tries to make the voltage between its inputs zero. Let's name the two inputs (the 200Hz and the 20Hz ones) \$u_1\$ and \$u_2\$, and the output voltage \$u_3\$. You can now use a nodal equation for the non-inverting input (let's say every current is flowing to the right):

\$i_1+i_2=i_3\$

\${u_1-0 \over {1k\Omega}} + {u_2-0 \over {1k\Omega}}={0-u_3 \over {1k\Omega}}\$

Now multiply the equation with 1k\$\Omega\$:

\$u_1+u_2=-u_3\$

There you have the sum of the two input voltages on the output (multiplied by minus one).

Comment: That makes sense. But why then the current is not flowing from u1 to u2 as would be expected for 2 voltage sources in parallel? Why is it only flowing from voltage sources to the ground? Thanks!

Comment: First: They are not in parallel. They don't have a single common terminal, let alone two. The current can only flow to the ground (or from the ground to themselves, talking about AC signals), because the node between the inputs, the virtual ground, is a fixed value. That means, the currents through the left side resistors are fixed as well: both their ends have exactly defined potentials. Any excess current must flow through the only remaining path, the feedback resistor.

Answer (score 2):

Actually not the voltages add up but the currents.
All currents flowing to the negative input (which is assumed to be high impedance, i.e. "open" and at ground level) must add up to 0.

Since currents are proportional to the voltage across resistors, the voltage of the output must be equal in magnitude (but opposite in sign) to the SUM of the voltages at the left terminals of the two resitors.

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically, how can 2 voltages in parallel add up when negative
>   input (ideally) has infinite resistance?

1. You can make the reasonable assumption that an op-amp has really high gain.
2. With really high gain there can hardly be any difference in the voltage between the non-inverting and inverting input.
3. If there were a measurable difference then, due to the op-amp's massive gain, the output from the op-amp would probably be hard against one of the power rails.
4. But it isn't, therefore the voltage at the inverting input is "virtually" the same as the voltage at the non-inverting input
5. With non-inverting input at 0V, the inverting input is "virtually" at 0V because of the high op-amp gain.
6. This means that your input resistors can be said to connect between signal and "virtual" ground.
7. This means that the current that flows in either input resistor is subject only to its input voltage and its resistor value.
8. This in turn means that both signal-input currents (due to input 1 and input 2) flow also through the feedback resistor as I1+I2
9. This in turn means the op-amp's output voltage is feedback-resistor*(I1+I2) - don't forget the virtual ground when you read this last sentence.